# What is the pixel density/ DPI of figsize in Pandas series plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

With a Pandas Series (`pandas.core.series.Series`), there is a convenient `plot()` method ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html)) for producing, e.g., a bar chart.

This `plot()` method takes a `figsize` argument that is tuple-valued; the width and height in inches.

> figsize : a tuple (width, height) in inches

However, I can't find any documentation on what the assume pixel density/ DPI/ PPI is for each inch. There doesn't seem to be any way to specify what it should be, either. Based on the output image size, I'm guessing it is pretty low (e.g., 72 dpi), but would like to know what it is so when I'm teaching this method I can provide a reasonable explanation for the output. Here's a sample usage:

```
species_counts = surveys.groupby('species_id')['record_id'].count()
type(species_counts) # `pandas.core.series.Series`
species_counts.plot(figsize = (9, 6), kind = 'bar')
```

I understand this method is based on `matplotlib` but, unfortunately, the method on a Pandas Series does not take a `dpi` argument (results in `AttributeError: Unknown property dpi`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underlying `matplotlib` commands to specify `dpi`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(dpi=1000)
species_counts = surveys.groupby('species_id')['record_id'].count()
species_counts.plot(figsize = (9, 6), kind = 'bar')

fig.get_dpi()  # 1000
```

Alternatively, if you just want to know what the default `dpi` is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

species_counts = surveys.groupby('species_id')['record_id'].count()
species_counts.plot(figsize = (9, 6), kind = 'bar')

fig = plt.gcf()    
fig.get_dpi()
```

I don't think there's a canonical answer, I'm pretty sure the exact answer will depend on what backend you are using, and maybe on your hardware.